# How to use online payment options to merchants’ websites on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-processing

How to implement payment options by multiple banks on merchant's website.

Comment: Try this tutorials from ryan bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great tutorials on rails casts by Ryan Bates, check out the [E-Commerce tutorials here](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=23)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Active Merchant](http://activemerchant.org/) for payment processing.

If you are looking for a fully functional commerce platform built on rails, then [Spree Commerce](http://spreecommerce.com/) is the way you want to go.